# Getting total score from best 2 scores per member

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an issue where the code below works out the total score of all inputted scored for members instead of limiting it to the best 2. It seems to dislike duplicate scores and won't add them in some members have less than 2 scores showing when they have more than 2 scores.

```
create table members(id int, name char, handicap int);

insert into members(id, name, handicap)
values(1, 'Bob', 12);

insert into members(id, name, handicap)
values(2, 'John', 14);

create table results(member_id int, course_id int, score int, position int);

insert into results(member_id int, course_id int, score int, position int)
values(1,1,36,1);

insert into results(member_id int, course_id int, score int, position int)
values(1,2,34,2);

insert into results(member_id int, course_id int, score int, position int)
values(2,1,27,2);

insert into results(member_id int, course_id int, score int, position int)
values(2,2,35,2);

insert into results(member_id int, course_id int, score int, position int)
values(2,3,35,2);

insert into results(member_id int, course_id int, score int, position int)
values(1,3,38,1);
```

AND GET data

```
SELECT name, handicap, best, total FROM
(SELECT name, id, curr_handicap as handicap,  GROUP_CONCAT(score order by score DESC SEPARATOR ' | ') as best,
sum(score) as total
 FROM members m join (SELECT member_id, score, course_id
  FROM results m
  WHERE(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM results mT
    WHERE mT.member_id = m.member_id and mT.score >= m.score) <= 2 )  r
    on m.id = r.member_id 
    group by member_id
    ORDER BY total, member_id DESC, name, MIN(course_id) ASC
) AS T1
group by name
order by total DESC
```

I want the desired result to look like this:

```
    <table>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Handicap</td><td>Total score</td><td>Best 2 scores</td> 
   </tr>
    <tr><td>Bob</td><td>12</td><td>74</td><td>38 | 36</td></tr>
    <tr><td>John</td><td>14</td><td>70</td><td>35 | 35</td></tr>
    </table>
```

However I only get the total score from all the players scores and the best 2 scores don't always show if they are the same.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Sorry I have added some test data and the result I want, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested or stuck for something like this.
I needed to display the best 6 scores for each member in this table. I wanted the total score from the best 6 scores and not just the total overall score for the member also.

The solution is below using variables it was much simpler than I thought it would be!

```
SELECT name, handicap, best, total FROM
 (SELECT name, id, curr_handicap as handicap,  GROUP_CONCAT(score order by score DESC 
 SEPARATOR ' | ') as best,
 sum(score) as total
 FROM members m join (select member_id, score, course_id, result_id
 from
   (
     SELECT member_id, score, course_id, result_id,
     (@row:=if(@prev=member_id, @row +1, if(@prev:= member_id, 1, 1))) rn
     FROM results t
     CROSS JOIN (select @row:=0, @prev:=null) c
     order by member_id, score desc 
   ) src
 where rn <= 6
 order by member_id, score)  r
 on m.id = r.member_id 
 group by member_id
 ORDER BY total, member_id DESC
 ) AS T1
group by name
order by total DESC");
```